# Login with OneTimePassword after ChangePassword API with 2FA enabled

Tags: two-factor-authentication, fusionauth

How does FusionAuth work if you just completed the Change Password API, tried to re-login using the Login API with the `oneTimePassword` token, but you have two-factor enabled? Because, from my understanding, it sounds like I would need to interrupt the re-authentication flow for the user to get their two-factor code, after they just changed their password while already being logged in. Is this desired behavior? This line in the docs makes me think this is unintentional:

> For this reason, this API will return a oneTimePassword that is intended to be used programatically after a Change Password request completes to keep the user logged in and provide a better user experience. A successful login will return you a new access token (JWT) and a refresh token. This will allow you to make the change password workflow seamless to the user.

Comment: Are you asking how it should work, or how you're observing it work? When using the Login API with the `oneTimePassword` the Two Factor requirement should be bypassed.  If you are receiving a `242` from the Login API indicating Two Factor is required, this is either a bug or an edge case that we have not considered.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! My point was to understand what the intent was for it to do. I haven't tried it yet, but will do so and report back.